# How to get single row when foreign key is similar

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

I have a table tbl_issue with columns

```
> serial_no.
 Issue_no. (f.k) 
From_Section 
To_Section
+-----+---------------+-------------+-------------+
| id  | issue no      | from section| to_section  |
+-----+---------------+-------------+-------------+
| 1   | 223           |   MFA       | N/A         |
| 2   | 223           |   N/A       | LOG         |
+----------+----------+-------------+--------------+
```

When I query the table on issue no. I get two rows, can anyone kindly help how can I get a single record and no 'N/A'

Comment: [tag:mysql] or [tag:oracle]?  They are mutually exclusive (one is a FOSS product that happens to now be owned by the Oracle Corporation; the other is a proprietary, closed-source, commercial product that is the namesake of that company).

Comment: Perhaps it would have been sensible to update the existing record in the first place, rather than insert a new one?  If separate records are indeed necessary, please define what should happen in the presence of more than two for a single issue.

Comment: They are N/A or null??

Comment: Show us the query that you are using

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer if it helped you?

Answer (score 2):

For the example you gave this would work:

```
WITH combined AS
(
SELECT    i.issue_no,
          CASE WHEN i.from_section = 'N/A' THEN i2.from_section ELSE i.from_section END from_section,
          CASE WHEN i.to_section = 'N/A' THEN i2.to_section ELSE i.to_section END to_section
FROM          dbo.tbl_issue i
INNER JOIN  dbo.tbl_issue i2
    ON    i2.issue_no = i.issue_no
)

SELECT    DISTINCT *
FROM          combined c
WHERE     c.from_section <> 'N/A' AND c.to_section <> 'N/A'
```

This is supposing that the 'N/A' is does not mean NULL...If you meant NULL replace "= 'N/A'" with IS NULL and replace "<> 'N/A'" with IS NOT NULL

Comment: Thanks for the query, I shall try and approve accordingly.